# Problems trying to reset ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, encryption

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, as I always do, but this time I tried to encrypt my folders. Then when the installation finishes I reset the computer, but the encrypt password does not work.
I google a little bit and I decide to reinstall Ubuntu, but computer displays me this message:

```
[0.415515]--[end kerne1] panic-not syncing:VFS:Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I tried to type something but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boot another time the USB with the .iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), and then reinstall Ubuntu.